# Does RandomAccessFile in java read entire file in memory?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I need to read last n lines from a large file (say 2GB). The file is UTF-8 encoded.

Would like to know the most efficient way of doing it. Read about RandomAccessFile in java, but does the seek() method , read the entire file in memory. It uses native implementation so i wasn't able to refer the source code.

Comment: And no, `seek()` does not read *anything* into memory, let alone the whole file. You have full control.

Comment: I read through that question, but i would like to understand, if the file if UTF-8 encoded, then is use of RandomAccessFile discouraged ?

Comment: Disagree with duplicate. This focuses more on RandomAccessFile, while the other is more about the application, and doesn't even mention RAF.

Answer (score 6):

1. RandomAccessFile.seek just sets the file-pointer current position, no bytes are read into memory.
2. Since your file is UTF-8 encoded, it is a text file. For reading text files we typically use BufferedReader, Java 7 even added a convinience method File.newBufferedReader to create an instance of a BufferedReader to read text from a file. Though it may be inefficient for reading last n lines, but easy to implement.
3. To be efficient we need RandomAccessFile and read file backwards starting from the end. Here is a basic example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int n = 3;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("test", "r")) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (long length = f.length(), p = length - 1; p > 0 && lines.size() < n; p--) {
            f.seek(p);
            int b = f.read();
            if (b == 10) {
                if (p < length - 1) {
                    lines.add(0, getLine(bout));
                    bout.reset();
                }
            } else if (b != 13) {
                bout.write(b);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
}

static String getLine(ByteArrayOutputStream bout) {
    byte[] a = bout.toByteArray();
    // reverse bytes
    for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1; j > i; i++, j--) {
        byte tmp = a[j];
        a[j] = a[i];
        a[i] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(a);
}
```

It reads the file byte after byte starting from tail to ByteArrayOutputStream, when LF is reached it reverses the bytes and creates a line.

Two things need to be improved:

1. buffering
2. EOL recognition

Comment: Can you include how to use BufferedReader without reading the whole file?

Comment: Since it reads line by line it is not reading the whole file into memory

Comment: I would say that since it is reading line by line from the start, it is reading the whole file into memory, even if it doesn't load the whole file at once.

Comment: Could you explain what are those numbers(10 and 13) mean that you used in your if statement?

Comment: It's newline - 1 or 2 characters \n (10) and \r (13) see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

If you need Random Access, you need RandomAccessFile. You can convert the bytes you get from this into UTF-8 if you know what you are doing.

If you use BuffredReader, you can use skip(n) by number of characters which means it has to read the whole file.

---

A way to do this in combination; is to use FileInputStream with skip(), find where you want to read from by reading back N newlines and then wrap the stream in BufferedReader to read the lines with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: So does it mean, end of day, i end up reading the whole file in memory ?

Comment: Not if you do as I suggest. If you use BufferedReader alone, it will read the whole file, which is what I don't suggest you do that.

Comment: Can you please share a snippet of code for this novice :( .I want to reach end of file, trace back to n lines, and then read the n lines to my memory

Comment: You need to read the end of the file as a `byte[]`, if you see the number of newlines you need, you know where to skip to. If you don't you need to read back some more until you do.  Note: if a file has no newlines, you could end up reading the whole file.  I suggest you give it a go ;)